# Re-render a page without old data

Tags: node.js, express, pug

In my application if I call res.render like so

```
res.render( 'index',
            {list:output1})
```

It will display correctly for the first page. However if for example the first page ouputs like this

```
1
2
3
```

and I press the back button and load my other page which calls this res.render which should look like this

```
A
B
```

the result will have extra from the first output, like so

```
A
B
3
```

Is there way to 'refresh' it so no old data will be included?

Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't happen. Render happens at the server, not at client. so back btn will not make a difference. Pls post more code.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake on my part....

I realized my output variable was global. By declaring it in my function (making a new, empty output each time) I didnt have this problem